# inserting records using Apex Web service

Tags: apex, callout, dml, apex-webservice

The user has access to apex class.I am trying to insert accounts using apex web service. and making a callout using apex.
This is my code.but it seems that the apex web service is not receiving the serialized accounts. Accounts are not inserted.

Can somebody please help?

```
public class SEAM_BulkUpload_Handler {
    public static HTTPResponse calloutinsertHeaderAccount(list<Account> account){
         HTTPResponse response=null;
        String accountstring = JSON.serialize(account);
       //String newStr = accountstring.substring(1, accountstring.length()-1);
        System.debug('accountstring handler'+accountstring);
        //System.debug('newStr'+newStr);
        Http h = new Http();
        Httprequest req = new Httprequest();
        req.setBody(accountstring);
        req.setEndpoint('https://abg--mtwizard.lightning.force.com/services/apexrest/Accounts');
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth '+UserInfo.getSessionId());
         response=h.send(req);
        System.debug('response'+response);
        return response;
    }
}
```

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/Accounts/*')
global with sharing class SEAM_InsertAccountWebService {
   
    @HttpPost
    global static list<Account> createAccount(String accountstring) {
        System.debug('accountstring'+accountstring);
    list<Account> account= (list<Account>) JSON.deserialize(accountstring, list<Account>.class);
        insert account;
        //System.debug('account'+account.id);
        return account;
        
    }   
}
```

Comment: welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to visit the [help], scroll through the [tour], and read [ask]. Specifics/Details are helpful in these scenarios - what does the post message look like you are testing with? Does the profile of the user have access to the apex class? You can [edit] your question to add more details.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the changes I would make to allow your `POST` method to capture the content of the `HTTP Request` body. Although I am providing these changes, there are a number of concerns with the implementation from the point of view of calling inhouse APIs from inhouse Apex and expecting SObjects to be sent/received with a database action following.

Define your content type in the HTTP header:

```
req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
```

Remove the input parameter in the `POST` method:

```
@HttpPost
global static List<Account> createAccount() { ... }
```

Deserialise the body of the HTTP Request in the `POST` method:

```
String body = RestContext.request.requestBody.toString();
List<Account> accounts = (List<Account>) JSON.deserialize(body, List<Account>.class);
```

Note, at this point you have a List of Accounts that already exist in the database. When you attempt to perform an insert, you will receive an expected exception. I would assume you are calling `createAccount` with a JSON representation of one or more **NEW** Accounts.